# Classical Heisenberg model and variational free energy for the mean field

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model

This is a homework question that I'm stuck on for 2 days, we are asked to analyze the mean field method for the Classical Heisenberg model using the variational free energy. The Hamiltonian is given by:

\begin{align*}
H=-J\sum_{<i,j>} S_i\cdot S_j-H\cdot\sum_iS_i
\end{align*}

The spins are unit vectors, and the join probability distribution is a product measure, meaning:

\begin{align*}
P(\{\Omega\})=p(\Omega_1)p(\Omega_2)\cdots p(\Omega_N)
\end{align*}

I want to write a variational free energy and then solve for $p(\Omega)$ by minimizing it using Euler-Lagrange equation. My attempt so far is:

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}=F_0+<H-H_0>_0
\end{align*}

The subscript 0 stands for the trial Hamiltonian that I chose

\begin{align*}
H_0=-m\cdot\sum_i S_i
\end{align*}

And m is in the direction of the external magnetic field H. This gave me:

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}=T\sum_i \ln{p(\Omega)}+<H>_0=T\sum_i \ln{p(\Omega)}+<-J\sum_{<i,j>} S_i\cdot S_j-H\cdot\sum_iS_i>_0
\end{align*}

I have no idea how to go forward and write this in term of $p(\Omega)$ and possibly $\frac{dp}{d\Omega}$ and then use Euler-Lagrange equation. any suggestions are welcome, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible approaches, that lead to different results. The first one is to use the usual mean-field and find $m$ that minimises ($N$ is the number of sites):
$$
F = F_0+\langle H-H_0\rangle
$$
with your $H_0 = -B\cdot \sum \sigma_i$ (changing notations to avoid future conflicts) giving the ensemble $p_0 = \frac{1}{Z_0}e^{-\beta H_0}$ (rescaled $m$ so that it is well defined in the thermodynamic limit with . You don't need Euler-Lagrange since you are just optimising three parameters. Just taking the gradient using (decorrelation of spins):
$$
\begin{align}
\langle \sigma_i\rangle_0 &= m\\
\langle \sigma_i\cdot \sigma_j\rangle_0 &= m^2\\
\partial_B F_0 &= -Nm \\
m &:=  \left(\coth (\beta |B|)-\frac{1}{\beta |B|}\right)\hat B
\end{align}
$$
with $\hat B = \frac{B}{|B|}$ the normalised vector corresponding to $m$ and $N$ the number of sites. You then obtain the usual self consistent equation:
$$
B = dJm
$$
with $d$ the average number of neighbours of a site (average degree of graph).

However, since you were talking about Euler-Lagrange and considering ansatz ensemble of independent spins, $p_0(\sigma) = \prod p(\sigma_i)$. Perhaps you are interested in the more general case when $p$ is not imposed to be of the form $p\propto \exp(-\beta B\cdot \sigma)$. I think that you had some difficulties because you did not revert to the original expression of free energy (there is no natural $H_0$ to identify):
$$
F = \langle H\rangle_0-TS_0
$$
with $S_0$ is the entropy of the ensemble $p_0$. The beginning is essentially the same:
$$
\begin{align}
\langle S_i\rangle_0 &= m\\
\langle S_i\cdot S_j\rangle_0 &= m^2\\
m &:=  \int d^2\sigma p(\sigma)\sigma
\end{align}
$$
with the integration over the unit sphere, I think this is what you were referring to $\Omega$ as in the solid angle. Usual derivatives are replaced by functional derivatives:
$$
\begin{align}
S_0 &= -N\int d^2\sigma p(\sigma)\ln p(\sigma) \\
\delta S_0 &= -N\int d^2\sigma(\ln p+1)\delta p \\
\delta m &= \int d^2\sigma \sigma \delta p
\end{align}
$$
with $\lambda$ a Lagrange multiplier since $p$ is varied while conserving normalisation. Adding a Lagrange multiplier to conserve the normalisation of $p$:
$$
\begin{align}
\delta F &= -NdJm\cdot\delta m -T\delta S_0 - \int d^2\sigma \lambda \delta p\\
&= N\int d^2\sigma\left[-dJm\cdot\sigma +T(\ln p+1)-\lambda\right]\delta p
\end{align}
$$
giving the self-consistent equation:
$$
\begin{align}
p(\sigma) &\propto \exp(\beta dJm\cdot\sigma) \\
m &=  \int d^2\sigma p(\sigma)\sigma
\end{align}
$$

This brings us back to the first approach. It means that out of all the possible distributions $p$, the ones coming from an effective external magnetic field are optimal. This justifies the first approach which may seem parachuted when introduced for the first time.

Hope this helps.